# Getting the last element of an array with a split in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the last array item after doing a split on a string using javascript.

```
    var str ="Watch-The-Crap-456".split('-')[this.length];
    console.log(str);​​​ 
   // want it to console log 456, now it consoles WATCH which is in array[0]
```

I tried doing `[this.length - 1]` to get me the last array item, but it gives me undefined, I know some of you might say create another variable to store the array, but it's interesting to see if we can keeps things shorter.

Comment: from the above provided code, there is no way of knowing what 'this' refers to

Comment: Even if this was valid, you're introducing an off by one error, as indexing is 0-based.

Comment: just do it in two lines. even if there was a one liner, it would be more difficult to read/understand/maintain.

Comment: What's the point? Why would you want to perform these actions on a string literal?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

How about:

```
"Watch-The-Crap-456".split('-').pop(); // returns 456
```

Comment: Be aware that you're creating a whole new array just to get one element from it, although this looks quite nice.

Comment: @lostsource what if i don't want `"456"` but instead `"Watch-The-Crap"` is there any `pop()` for that?

Comment: @ImranBughio you could use a combination of `substr()` and `lastIndexOf()` for that, no need for `pop()`

Answer (score 2):

`this` is defined in the deference (or at least does not reference the *array*).

A *naive* way would be two lines:

```
var str ="Watch-The-Crap-456".split('-');
console.log(str[str.length - 1]);​​​
```

See it [in action](http://jsfiddle.net/E2ywM/).

Answer (score 2):

Do you just want the **last element**? You could do this:

```
var str ="Watch-The-Crap-456";
console.log(str.slice(str.lastIndexOf('-')+1));​
```

In this case you must define your string first, which makes sense. I don't see *any* situation where you would want to get the last element from a string literal, you would just write `str = "456"` and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

Using underscore, which comes included with certain other libraries/frameworks, such as Backbone.js:

```
_.last(str.split('-'));
```

See: http://underscorejs.org/#last